# How is debugging possible without pdb files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

Situation:

- project DEP is a .NET class library project, being developed using VS2015, targeting .NET 4.5
- project A references DEP.dll (the *dll*, not the source code project itself)
- project A and DEP are part of separate solutions

When I build DEP in debug mode, and then I debug project A, I can still step into code from DEP, even though I see no pdb files in DEP's output folder. I wonder how debugging DEP is possible. I thought that pdbs were always needed to be able to debug. Or do dlls built in debug mode contain enough debug information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Every* program is debuggable. A debugger's most fundamental ability is to single-step processor instructions, look at processor registers and inspect memory.  Soul of the machine stuff.  What you'll never get without a PDB is the ability to look at the source code, single step statements and inspect named variables. Actually fixing bugs without a PDB is drastically impractical.

If you in fact see source code then that's not terribly surprising, the debugger is pretty good at locating a PDB.  If you didn't copy it yourself then the debugger can find the one in its original location, where the compiler put it, in the project's `obj\Debug` directory.  The path to that PDB is embedded in the executable file.  You can find out how it found it, use Debug > Windows > Modules, right-click the DLL and select Symbol Load Information.  It shows you everywhere the debugger looked for the PDB.

Comment: I do see source code. I wasn't aware that the executable file containts the PDB path